# Selenium - How to jump from one sibling to other

Tags: python, selenium, lxml, lxml.html

I am using Selenium-Python to Scrape the content at this link.
http://targetstudy.com/school/62292/universal-academy/

HTML code is like this,

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <i class="fa fa-mobile">
      ::before
    </i>
  </td>
  <td>8349992220, 8349992221</td>
 </tr>
```

I am not sure how to get the mobile numbers in  using the class="fa fa-mobile"
Could someone please help. Thanks

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import lxml.html
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

    path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
    browser.get('http://targetstudy.com/school/62292/universal-academy/')
    stuff = browser.page_source.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(stuff)
    address1 = tree.xpath('//td/i[@class="fa fa-mobile"]/parent/following-sibling/following-sibling::text()')

    print address1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `lxml.html` for this. `Selenium` is very powerful in [`Locating Elements`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html).

Pass `//i[@class="fa fa-mobile"]/../following-sibling::td` xpath expression to [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get('http://targetstudy.com/school/62292/universal-academy/')
>>> browser.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-mobile"]/../following-sibling::td').text
u'83499*****, 83499*****'
```

Note, added `*` for not showing the real numbers here.

Here the xpath first locates the `i` tag with the `fa fa-mobile` class, then goes to the parent and gets the next following `td` sibling element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think you answered the question. Your code just returns the following sibling, what if there are more after?